# Matrix 4x4 calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &  a+3 &  8 &  2 \\
0 &  0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & a-2 &  5 & 0 \\
0 & 10 & a &  a+3
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
w \\
\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
7 \\
-2 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm a bit stuck on this question... I need to find values of a for which this matrix has unique solutions.

So far I found that:

$z=\dfrac{7}{2}$
$y= \dfrac{-39}{2(a-2)}$
$w= \dfrac{(390-(7a^2)+14a)}{ (2(a-2)(a+3))}$

Can someone help to solve it completely?

Comment: A matrix equation $Ax = b$ has a unique solution iff the determinant of $A$ is non-zero.

Comment: but how to find determinant when you don't know some of the values...

Comment: Expand in minors  along the first column, then along the last.

Comment: @user65835 The determinant will be an expression containing $a$, and you will have to find the values of $a$ which makes the determinant non-zero. You calculate the determinant the same way you would for any matrix where you know all the entries.

Comment: I got determinant to be -2a^2- 2a +12 and what now?

Comment: Solve the equation $2a^2 - 2a + 12 = 0$.  Any $a$ that is **not** a solution is an $a$ such that the matrix has nonzero determinant.

Comment: so a= 2 and a=-3 are  the answers?

Comment: Hint: See [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+Inverse%5B%7B%7B1%2C+a%2B3%2C+8%2C+2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C2%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Ca-2%2C5%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C10%2Ca%2Ca%2B3%7D%7D%5D.%7B%7B0%2C7%2C-2%2C0%7D%7D%5ET+) result and make note of the comments! Clear?

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\det A &= 1\cdot\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 2 & 0\\a-2 & 3 & 0\\10 & a & a+3\end{array}\right)\quad (\text{expanded down first column})\\ &= 1\cdot(a+3)\cdot\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 2\\a-2 & 5\end{array}\right)\quad(\text{expanded down third column})\\ &= 1\cdot(a+3)\cdot\bigl(0-2(a-2)\bigr)\\ &= -2(a+3)(a-2).\end{align}$$

You'll have unique solutions if and only if $\det A\neq 0.$

---

In the comments below, you've come to see that as long as $a\neq 2$ and $a\neq -3$, then there will be a unique solution. Another way to see that is simply to look at the equations you've already generated: $$z=\frac72\tag{1}$$ $$y=\frac{-39}{2(a-2)}\tag{2}$$ $$w=\frac1{a+3}\left(\frac{195}{a-2}-\frac{7a}2\right)\tag{3}$$ Now $(2)$ doesn't even make *sense* when $a=2$, so in that case, we have *no* solutions at all. Likewise, $(3)$ makes no sense when $a=-3$, so we've no solutions in that case, either.

Otherwise, $(1)$ through $(3)$ make sense, and plugging the values thus determined into $$x=-(a+3)y-8z-2z\tag{4}$$ gives us the value of $x$ needed for the solution. Since $x,y,z,w$ are determined once we've plugged in our appropriate $a$, then the solution thus determined is unique.

Comment: so for question like "for which values of a this matrix has unique solution? " Do I say a= -3 and a=2 ?

Comment: @user65835: No, those are the values that make the determinant = 0, you want all other values. Is that clear?

Comment: so everything other than a=-3 and a=2 is a solution? or am I missing a point?

Comment: @user65835: Now you have the point and you even calculated some of the values. Think of $a$ as a free variable that you can make anything you want, except for those "bad" values that make your determinant $0$. If you look at my comment, you have the general solution for your variables based on $a$, but make sure to avoid those values of bad $a's$ cause look what they do to the results.

Comment: Amzoti you lost me, so if a is NOT equal to -3 or 2 the matrix has a general solution positive?

Comment: Now you want "positive"? What does that mean for *vectors"?? Their entries are positive or what?

Comment: I just need to know what is the final solution to it? Is the solution to say that if a is not equal to -3 or 2 then it has a general solution?

Comment: @user65835: If you don't put an "@" symbol in front of my name, I do not get a notification. Look at what happens to the [*determinant*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det+%7B%7B1%2C+0%2C+8%2C+2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C2%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C5%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C10%2C-3%2C0%7D%7D) when $a = -3$. Look at your the denominator of your expression for $w$. What happens to it when $a = - 3$. Can you make the connection now?

Comment: @Amzoti yes it will turn out to be zero. I get what you said, I just need to know what is the answer to this question "find values of a for which this matrix has unique solutions.". Would it be enough to say when a is not equal to -3 or 2?

Comment: @user65835. Correct, it is enough to say that, but also to state your reasons why! It would be good for you to look at the matrix again and see where those two values can be seen immediately from the matrix itself.